# Remove a column in DGV when adding datasource

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have just learned about *this way* of populating th datagridview.
Usually I just bind it as the access file is connected to the app.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM tblCpu"
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                dt.Load(dr)
                dgvComponents.DataSource = dt
            End Using
```

Now this code shows all the rows/colums of the table.. including ID.. in which I  don't want the user to see..
Is there a way to remove, or make the ID column invisible?

Comment: `dgvComponents.Columns("ID").Visible = False`.  the column name will be the name of the db Column.  you can also layout the columns you want, with the header you want and the width you want in the designer.  For each of Column, pick the right type, and set the `DataPropertyName` to the column to show for it.  Finally, set `AutoGenerateColumns` to False so it will use yours (only).

Comment: going to try this when finalizing a design, thank you for the info :)

Comment: specifying a column order in the SQL which omits the ID is good for read-only type data displays, but if you need the ID for UPDATEs or for related items, it is not the answer.  Hiding columns is simple, if you dont want to do a full layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your SQL statement to include only fields you want to see:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT City, Address, Country, Region FROM Customers"
```